# Flutter: How to get Firebase Auth Credentials to update email and password

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

So, In my flutter app, I am trying to add functionality to change email.

I used userData.updateEmail(email) method, but it gives this error:

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN, This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request., null)

On surfing for a solution on the Internet I got to know,  I need to reauthenticate user by this method: 
userData.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)

But I can't find a way to get credential to pass to reauthenticateWithCredential method.

Some code snippets (tho I feel they are unnecessary):

```
initUserData() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    setState(() {
      userData = user;
    });
  }

updateEmail(String value) async {
    // value is the email user inputs in a textfield and is validated
    userData.updateEmail(value);

  }
```

Note: I am using both login with google and password-email login.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem too and I found the solution. You can get the AuthCredential for the providers you're using like this:

```
EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email: 'email', password: 'password');
```

and

```
GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: '', accessToken: '')
```

Both methods return what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this mean i have to store the user's email and password in memory and later pass them on to getCredential if I want to reauthenticate? Seems like the wrong thing to do

Comment: Well I think you should save email, and ask user to input password when updating email.

Comment: How do I do a re-authentication for firebase phone auth?

Comment: how do i get idToken and accessToken?

Comment: @LimitlessClaver did you manage to find the solution? I am also looking for reauth based on phone.

Answer (score 17):

There is a re-authenticate method. You just need to obtain the user's password for calling the method.

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
AuthResult authResult = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(
  EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(
    email: user.email,
    password: password,
  ),
);

// Then use the newly re-authenticated user
authResult.user
```

Answer (score 4):

It is working for me

```
Future resetEmail(String newEmail) async {
    var message;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    firebaseUser
        .updateEmail(newEmail)
        .then(
          (value) => message = 'Success',
        )
        .catchError((onError) => message = 'error');
    return message;
  }
```

Comment: This would only work if user has recently logged in.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to change sensitive informations on Firebase you need to re-authenticate first to your account using your current credentials then you can update it.
Currently flutter has no reAuthenticate method for Firebase so you need to call **signInWithEmailAndPassword** or any other signIn method.

Comment: Well, Flutter has reauthenticateWithCredential method but it required a password. How will I get password without making user typing it again?

Comment: Except if you save the user passwords at first connexion using sharedPreferences or a database (which I don't really recommend). I don't think you really have another choice. It's classic security when you want to change sensitive information. Like typing your old password when you want to change to a new one.